# JSON Parsing with different keys inside BQ

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I have some issues with parsing column with JSON into 2 columns.
My data in table looks like this:

```
| Column1         | user_id        |
| --------------- | -------------- |
| {"key2": "1"}   | 1ab3           |
| {"key3": "5"}   | 4jj2           |
| {"key1": "3"}   | 48gi           |
| {"key5": "4"}   | kg99           |
```

I was trying to use offset and regexp:

```
 SELECT table.user_id,
    SPLIT(kv, ': ')[OFFSET(0)] AS Column1_key_type,
    SPLIT(kv, ': ')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS Column1_key_value
    FROM table,
    UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(table.Column1, r'("\w+":[^"]*)(?:,|})')) kv
```

but this return me the empty table.

So, the main problem that I don't know how to write the key from JSON to first column and its value to the second one.

I'd like to parse the first column to the next view:

| Column1_key_type | Column1_key_value |
| --- | --- |
| key2 | 1 |
| key3 | 5 |
| key1 | 3 |
| key5 | 4 |

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider this instead of using **regexp** function.

```sql
SELECT SPLIT(TRANSLATE(Column1, '{}" ', ''), ':')[OFFSET(0)] Column1_key_type,
       SPLIT(TRANSLATE(Column1, '{}" ', ''), ':')[OFFSET(1)] Column1_key_value
  FROM sample_table;
```

[image]

Comment: Lot of thanks! Works as expected.